# continue button not working under checkout in Billing information step

Tags: magento-1.9

"**continue**" button under "**Billing information**" in **checkout** is not working. I am trying below code and i got error as in image.

[image]

```
<?php

$id=rand().time();
if(isset($description)) {
    $description = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $description);
} else {
    $description = "";
}

?>
<div id="map-canvas<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>; height:<?php echo $height; ?>;max-width:100%;" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en&amp;callback=initialize"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        try{
            if(typeof(google) != "undefined"){ 
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo (float)$latitude; ?>, <?php echo (float)$longitude; ?> );
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas<?php echo $id; ?>'), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            title: " "
                           });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                infowindow.setContent('<?php echo $description; ?>');
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            }
        }catch(e){

        }   
    }
    window.onload = initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below way :

```
window.onload = initialize;
```